# How to implement Google AdMob service in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

While working with testing ads, it was fine, but with real ad units, it didn't show up, and most importantly how to implement For the module to attribute interactions with ads to your AdMob app properly you will need to add a googleMobileAdsAppId property to app.json under [platform].config."
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VQdY.png)

Answer (score 0):

change googleMoblieAppId to your own app id. The one you get from admob.

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "YourappName",
    "slug": "Slugname",
    "privacy": "public",
    "android": {
      "package": "in.learner.yourappname",
      "versionCode": 1,
      "config": {
        "googleMobileAdsAppId": "yourGoogleAppId goes here"
     }
    },
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android",
      "web" 
    ],

    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "config": {
        "googleMobileAdsAppId": "your GoogleAppId goes here"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Check the image i have attached, how to implement that in app.json